# The geometric models of generalised Baumslag-Solitar groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, gt.geometric-topology, geometric-group-theory

I am trying to understand a construction in the paper "[The large scale geometry of the higher Baumslag-Solitar groups](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00039-001-8232-6)", GAFA, Geometric and functional analysis 11, 1327–1343 (2001), [MR1878322](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1878322), [Zbl 1004.20024](https://zbmath.org/1004.20024), by Kevin Whyte ([Available also on Arxiv](https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.math/0405272)).

Let $G$ be a graph of groups of $\mathbb{Z}$(s) (both vertex and edge group is $\mathbb{Z}$), one can construct a $2$-complex $X_G$ on which $G$ acts properly discontinuously and cocompactly by isometries. I am able to construct the complex, and why it is homeomorphic to $T \times \mathbb{R}$, where $T$ is the Bass-Serre tree of $G$. I have trouble understanding how the group acts by isometries on $X_G$.

For Baumslag-Solitar group, $X_G$ seems to coincide with the Cayley Complex (universal cover of Presentation Complex). But how does it work with a Torus Knot Group (next simplest generalised Baumslag Solitar group)? E.g. how does it work with
$\mathbb{Z} *_{2\mathbb{Z} \cong 3\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Z} = \langle a, b | a^2 = b^3 \rangle$?

Comment: I do not see a question in your post.

Comment: We explain this in https://arxiv.org/abs/1212.6765

Comment: In the torus-knot case, the quotient isn’t quite a presentation complex, but it’s close.  Consider an interval $c$, with loops $a$ and $b$ attached at either end. Now attach a disc along the loop $a^2cb^{-3}c^{-1}$. The product of trees in question is the universal cover of the resulting complex.

Comment: Are you familiar with the paper of [Scott and Wall](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/abs/homological-group-theory/topological-methods-in-group-theory/A9868486C3815839B6263634C3DDF080), and in particular their construction of a graph of spaces associated to the graph of groups? The ordinary fundamental group of that graph of spaces is identified with the group $G$ (which is the "Bass-Serre" fundamental group of the given graph of spaces).

Comment: You can then put your favorite geometry on that graph of spaces and lift that to get a geometry on the universal cover, together with an isometric action of $G$. And you can then identify the universal cover with $T \times \mathbb R$ in your post.